# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

I'm using maven project with hibernate 4

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    <!-- will come with Hibernate core-->
</dependency>
```

and spring 3.2.0.RELEASE and jsf in run tomcat server i have this exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
```

this is my application-context.xml :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/gestionnotes"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="fr.ensa.agadir.model"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
         <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.ensa.agadir"/>
</beans>
```

this is my pom.xml :

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>
> 4.0.0  EnsaAgadir
>     EnsaGestionNotes   war
>     EnsaGestionNotes Maven Webapp
>     1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   4.0.0
>         EnsaAgadir
>         EnsaGestionNotes
>         war
>         EnsaGestionNotes Maven Webapp
>         1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> ```
>   <!-- les proprietés 3.1.4 -->
>   <properties>
>       <logback.version>0.9.15</logback.version>
>       <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
>       <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
>       <env>LOCAL</env>
>   </properties>
>
>   <dependencies>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
>           <version>3.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
>           <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
>           <version>1.1.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
>           <version>1.9.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-beanutils-bean-collections</artifactId>
>           <version>1.8.3</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
>           <version>2.0.1</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
>           <version>2.2.6</version>
>           <scope>runtime</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
>           <version>2.2.6</version>
>           <scope>runtime</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- primafaces -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
>           <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
>           <version>5.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
>           <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
>           <version>1.0.9</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Junit 4 -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>junit</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>           <version>4.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
>            <!-- will come with Hibernate core-->
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>           <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
>           <type>jar</type>
>           <scope>compile</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
>           <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
>           <type>jar</type>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
>           <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
>           <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
>           <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple 
>           backend -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
>           <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
>           <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and 
>           javassist -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
>           <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
>           <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
>           <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
>           <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
>           <version>0.9.1.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- spring -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>           <scope>compile</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>           <scope>compile</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>           <scope>compile</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>           <scope>compile</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- MySql jdbc -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>           <version>5.1.9</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- jstl -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>
>       <!-- javax.servlet -->
>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
>           <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
>           <version>1.1.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- javax.servlet -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>           <version>2.5</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
>           <version>2.1</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- upload -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
>           <version>1.3.1</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- upload -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax</groupId>
>           <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
>           <version>7.0</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- Itext -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
>           <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
>           <version>2.1.7</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>           <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
>           <version>3.5-beta3</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>   </dependencies>
>
>   <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>3.1</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <source>1.7</source>
>                   <target>1.7</target>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>       <resources>
>         <resource>
>           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>           <filtering>true</filtering>
>         </resource>
>       </resources>
>   </build>
>   <repositories>
>       <repository>
>           <id>jboss-repository</id>
>           <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository</name>
>           <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/</url>
>       </repository>
>       <repository>
>           <id>prime-repo</id>
>           <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
>           <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
>           <layout>default</layout>
>       </repository>
>       <repository>
>           <id>java.net2</id>
>           <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
>           <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
>       </repository>
>   </repositories>
> </project>
> ```

Comment: We need all your pom.xml and application context configuration to can help you.

Comment: Well, i am seeing somethings.

Comment: now i have this exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/h‌​ibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;

Answer (score 0):

First, try to configure properly your dependencies, you are using Hibernate 4.3.5 with Hibernate-entitymanager 4.1.9... That don't look very well...

Use this aproximation, and try again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- optional -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: now i have this exception :
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;

Comment: Although I have never used entitymanager, I think that your config is wrong. Look at this tutorial to detect inconsistent dependencies. http://pauliusmatulionis.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/using-hibernate-over-jpa-entitymanager.html